# Verbos con sus respectivas preposiciones

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, preposiciones

Cada vez que busco en un diccionario inglés-español un verbo (en inglés), el diccionario muestra generalmente la preposición que acompaña a ese verbo, a veces suelen ser dos o más preposiciones. Es obvio que dependiendo de la preposición, el significado cambia, más si hablamos de los famosos *phrasal verbs*. Esto se puede ver en el mismo diccionario inglés-español para el caso del español, pero no se ve si voy a un diccionario de solo español. Me explico con ejemplos.

El verbo *depender*, ¿qué preposición usualmente le sigue? *De*. ¿Cómo lo sabe? Porque lo vio en un diccionario (inglés-español o español), porque lo ha escuchado una y otra vez o porque quizás sabe que la traducción de *to depend on* es *depender de*.

Pongamos otro verbo, *pensar*. ¿Qué preposición usualmente le sigue? Me inclino por *en*:

> Pienso en el trabajo que no hice.

¿Hay más preposiciones **permitidas**? Sí:

> ¿Qué piensa *de* mí?
>   Pienso *con* mi corazón.
>   Pienso *sin* mi cabeza.

¿Cuáles de todas las preposiciones son las permitidas, las que tienen sentido para el verbo *pensar*? Al parecer varias, cada una de ellas realiza, por supuesto, su función, cada una cambia el sentido de la oración.

Volviendo al verbo *depender*. ¿Hay construcciones que no tengan *de*? ¿Hay alguna regla que lo dicte? Con el verbo *hablar* uno puede encontrar que le siguen preposiciones como *con*, *de*, *hacia*. Con *saber*, le siguen preposiciones como *de*, *sin*. Un verbo más:

> Ríen *con* ella.
>   Ríen *por* ella.
>   Ríen *de* ella.
>   Ríen *sin* ella.

Sé que algunas suenan bien. Por eso mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo se sabe qué preposición debe acompañar a un verbo para que tenga sentido la oración en español? ¿Hay alguna regla con respecto a ello?**

Comment: -1: Hola David, bienvenido al sitio web. Tu pregunta es muy extensa y hace muchas preguntas a la misma vez, no es lo suficientemente concisa como para saber rápidamente lo que deseas saber. Intenta mejorar la calidad de la pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Has probado el [Diccionario Esencial de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/desen/)? En los ejemplos de uso suelen escribir con mayúsculas las preposiciones propias de cada verbo: "Soñe CON ella", "Pensé EN ella", "Hablé DE ella".

Naturalmente, no aparecen todas. Muchas preposiciones con su significado propio genérico se pueden usar con casi cualquier verbo: "Soñé sin ti", "Comí sin ti", "Dormí sin ti", "Hablé sin ti".

Tu problema me recuerda al chiste del perro que comía con el rabo... porque ningún perro come sin él :-D. Lo que quiero decir es que hay básicamente tres tipos de preposiciones que acompañan al verbo:

1. **Perífrasis**. Por ejemplo "Voy A comer". Similar a los *phrasal verbs* en inglés, el significado del verbo cambia total o parcialmente cuando se usa con esa preposición. Estas perífrasis siempre vienen en el diccionario.
2. [**Suplemento** o **complemento de régimen**](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_de_r%C3%A9gimen). Son complementos del verbo que llevan una preposición (a veces varias) específica para cada verbo. Deberían estar documentadas en el "Diccionario Esencial". Por ejemplo: "Eso depende DEl tiempo", "Confía EN mí".
3. **Complemento circunstancial**. Complementos del verbo con significado arbitrario, que pueden acompañar a cualquier verbo para el que tenga sentido su significado. En estos complementos la preposición es específica del complemento, no del verbo. "Canto EN la ducha", "Pienso EN la ducha", "Me peino EN la ducha". Estos usos no están documentados en cada verbo, pues la lista sería interminable.

Comment: No sabía que había un diccionario esencial; para mayor sorpresa trae más ejemplos cuando consulto algunos verbos. No dudo que el diccionario aclare algunas dudas, pero mi pregunta es más si puedo utilizar casi todos las preposiciones con un verbo, si tiene sentido utilizar tal preposición con tal verbo. Estamos de acuerdo que en algunos casos es más saberlo, tal como muestran los ejemplos que dio. Cambie de preposición, ¿tiene sentido? ¿cómo lo sabe?

Comment: @David en la mayoría de los casos, es posible hacer un cambio de preposición que conlleve un igual cambio de sentido.  Pero las preposiciones de régimen son efectivamente idiomáticos.  A veces coinciden con lo que nosotros (como anglohablantes) imaginamos que sea la relación espacial/interaccional/temporal, pero en muchos casos no.  En inglés, hay algunos lingüistas que prefieren llamar a estas preposiciones (que como elemento obligatorio de un verbo) como «partículos» en vez de «preposiciones» o «adverbios» (como a veces son).  En español, igual con el inglés, hay que memorizar :(

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a la pregunta de cómo se sabe qué preposición pueden acompañar a un verbo en español, un recurso **en papel** muy útil para resolver este tipo de preguntas se encuentra en el Diccionario de Uso de las Preposiciones Españolas, de Emili Slager.

Comment: 800 páginas, casi nada, pero no importa, lo miraré.

Comment: @David, jaja. Bueno, todos los diccionarios sueles ser largos.